# Type mismatch: inferred type is HomeFragment but Fragment was expected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo un NavigationView con sus Fragments para cambiar de vista y para llevarlo acabo cree un metodo "setupFragment(fragment: Fragment)" con un parametro de tipo Fragment para que ahí pueda poner todos los fragments que cree, pero luego de implementarlo me sale un error diciendo que tengo que poner un objeto de tipo fragment y eso me genera rareza ya que estoy poniendo un fragment.

*MenúActivity:

```
package com.example.gonzalo.examenparcial

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.MenuItem
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_menu.*


class MenuActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    lateinit var tb: Toolbar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)

        tb = toolbar as Toolbar
        tb.title = "NATURALEZA"

        setupNavigation()

        setupFragment(HomeFragment())

        navigation.menu.getItem(0).isChecked = true
    }

    private fun setupNavigation() {
        val toogle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, tb, R.string.drawerAbierto, R.string.drawerCerrado)

        toogle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = true

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toogle)
        toogle.syncState()
        navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    private fun setupFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).commit()
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.arbol -> setupFragment(ArbolFragment())
            R.id.planta_semilla -> setupFragment(PlantaFragment())
            R.id.grano_semilla -> setupFragment(SemillaFragment())
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }

        /*else if(HomeFragment().isVisible || LlegadasFragment().isVisible || SalidasFragment().isVisible){
            MapsActivity()
        }*/

        else{
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

*activity_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        app:itemTextColor="#009688"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity = "start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*Build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gonzalo.examenparcial"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

*El error que me genera:

```
D:\WorkSpaces\Examen_Parcial\app\src\main\java\com\example\gonzalo\examenparcial\MenuActivity.kt: (27, 23): Type mismatch: inferred type is HomeFragment but Fragment was expected

D:\WorkSpaces\Examen_Parcial\app\src\main\java\com\example\gonzalo\examenparcial\MenuActivity.kt: (48, 41): Type mismatch: inferred type is ArbolFragment but Fragment was expected

D:\WorkSpaces\Examen_Parcial\app\src\main\java\com\example\gonzalo\examenparcial\MenuActivity.kt: (49, 50): Type mismatch: inferred type is PlantaFragment but Fragment was expected

D:\WorkSpaces\Examen_Parcial\app\src\main\java\com\example\gonzalo\examenparcial\MenuActivity.kt: (50, 49): Type mismatch: inferred type is SemillaFragment but Fragment was expected
```

*Mas errores

```
Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la clase HomeFragment? Al menos la parte de los imports y la declaración de la clase

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is HomeFragment but Fragment was expected

el problema es que tu clase `HomeFragment` no esta extendiendo de `Fragment`

```
public class HomeFragmentextends Fragment {
   ...
   ...
}
```